# How to access protected variables of a child

Tags: c++, oop

I read the following statement , I am not sure if it's true, if it is can you elaborate with an example.

> The child has access to the same member variables of the base class
>   that is of the same INSTANCE.

The question I have though, is how to access protected variables of a child

```
  class A
    {
     private:
       class B* myBclass; 
     protected:
       int bc; 
     }

    class ChildofA : public A
    {
      public:
         childofA() {};
    }

    class B
    {
      public :
       B() {};
       virtual void fun1(A* anA);
    }


    class childofB : public B
    {
      public :
        void fun1(A* anA) 
           {
              anA.bc=1; << Problem here 
            }

    }
```

The above code complains about the fact that that variable bc is protected.
I'd like to have fun1() in ChildofB retrieve the variable bc of the instance of the child class ChildofA. How do you go about fixing this (without friend method and get/setter).

Comment: I don't think you can. A protected member, by definition, requires a setter or a friend method. You are simply trying to access a protected member, and the inheritance doesn't matter in this equation.

Comment: Why declare `bc` `protected` if you want to access it from outside the class?

Comment: Technically (but don't do this!!) you can declare the class childofB a friend class (not a method) of class A. Rather rework your interfaces.

Answer (score 3):

That means that `childOfA` has access to `bc` despite it being declared by `A`. The child has access to all public and protected instance variables. Protected means is "private, but to me and to my descendants, rather than just to me".

Inheritance doesn't give anything in the `B` hierarchy the ability to see the private storage of things in the `A` hierarchy. Declare a `friend` if you really must, though it's probably poor style, or if `bc` is meant to be accessible to other classes then make it public.